# ionic div border color change in ionic android by code

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

please help me out for changing border-color for div element in ionic , iam new to ionic ., i am able to change background color and tried in the same way as like that

//Is this is the correct way ?style.border-style or style.border

```
<div class="box" *ngIf="hide" [style.border-style]="aColor">
    <ion-item no-lines text-wrap>
</div>
```

Comment: Please refer to this post : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you put more information?? ionic version? some code reference, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses different style for platforms.

You can test app by running `ionic serve` with google chrome.

Below document explain how to test for different devices in chrome

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/